# Add text to a column if calculated column contains a certain number

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I have a SP online list with several number columns that are used for scoring. A numerical score is input into each column. I have an 'Overall' column (calculated column) that adds up the column scores. I want to add a new column called 'Overall Rating' and add specific text if the score is 0-6, 7-9, or 10-12. For example, if the score is 12, then I want 'XYZ' to show as text in the column. Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this calculated formula for Result Column:

`=IF(AND([Score]>=0,[Score]<=6), "0-6 Displayed content", IF([Score]<=9,"7-9 Displayed content",IF([Score]<=12,"10-12 Displayed content","")))`

Here is the result of my test:
[image]